# Tips for designing governmental internal systems

Tags: css, template-design, template

I have been asked to design a template for an internal use to register and document equipment for a government sector. The system will be used locally by employees only in the sector and will not be available to the public.

My question is, do I have to make it responsive even though I know they will use it only on PCs. What are the best tips for designing such a formal internal system and are there any samples. I have searched a lot but what i found is only for public use.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you haven't been handed several large folders with all of the legal requirements for user interfaces in these environments...

Comment: Ask them what they want. How do you know they will only use on PCs forever?

Comment: I don't work for the government, but I work for a large corporation.  On a scale that large, the IT Department usually determines which browser they will support.  Ours supports IE only, they won't even allow you to install Firefox or Chrome.  So, our web-based apps are all done specifically for IE.  What ever department you're working for may have similar limitations.  I would ask to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

#### Guidelines / Requirements

If this is in any way governmental, there will be some kind of requirements and/or guidelines you need to work by. I don't know where you are but I'm sure this will be the case anywhere. If you havn't been told about these, look for them. Theres a possibility someone isn't doing their job properly and you finding out *after* spending a big chunk of your time doing things *wrong*.

#### Responsiveness

There is no need, at all, for any website, web-app, whatever it is, *not* to be responsive. You say it will only be used on PCs, do you really know that? Who's to say the department doesn't get funding for a bunch of new iPads in 6 months?

#### Design for Usability

Remember the people using this are working, this is a tool for them to do their job. Try and keep it within what people are used to, if you have access to any of the other systems this department uses, look at those first. Don't try and make it 'pretty', don't try and make it 'fun' and don't try to make it *too* personal. Make it clean, functional and accessible. That's all you should care about. Ease of use is your number 1 priority.

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer my question ,but i have looked for their other systems but they dont like it they ask for better design ,that is why i am asking ,and yes i am the programmer and the designer some one is not doing his job :)

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you are designing so I wouldn't know what to search for but I would say that the whole internal vs public thing shouldn't matter. You can always ask another question as a critique of your current design (you can always remove/replace any information directly relating to the organisation). Keep in mind there are [requirements for critique question](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/681) though.